# Trigger on Delete (Before/After) is created successfully but on deletion of data gives an error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers, eventtrigger

I have two tables here, one of Employees and other of Departments. The department table's primary key is acting as a foreign key in Employees table.

What I am trying to do here is this that whenever the user deletes a record from Department table, it first deletes all the employees of that department from the employees table and then delete the row from the department table. Since it must delete from employees table first I am using `Before` trigger here.

This is the trigger I created (and it compiled successfully)

```
create or replace trigger delete_department_employees
before delete
on dept 
for each row 
begin 
delete from emp 
where deptno = :old.deptno;
end; 
/
```

Now, I wrote this command to delete the record from department table,

```
delete from dept 
where deptno = 10
```

But, I got this error:

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (HASSANASHAS.SYS_C007000) violated - child record found
ORA-06512: at "HASSANASHAS.DELETE_DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEES", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HASSANASHAS.DELETE_DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEES'
```

Just to be clear, I also tried using `after delete` instead of `before delete`, and that time also I was faced with same error.

Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this error and also how can I solve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a trigger here?  It would be more appropriate to declare your foreign key constraint to cascade deletes.  Is this a homework assignment where you are required to use a trigger?

Comment: Your delete is failing because the non-cascading foreign key constraint is being enforced. You can't delete rows from dept until _after_ all child records from emp are deleted or updated to point to a different dept record, so your trigger will never work. @JustinCave is correct - it would be better to use a foreign key with cascade delete enabled here; then deleting the dept record will automatically delete any child records in emp; no need for a trigger or a second transaction of any kind. Otherwise you will need to first delete all the affected emp records and _then_ delete the dept record.

Comment: Your trigger as posted works. [Here is a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7ac1c0474728302963a0e049f0d675f2).  So whatever constraint `HASSANASHAS.SYS_C007000` is, it's not a foreign key on EMP. This demonstrates the value of **naming constraints**. A constraint name which followed the standard practice of referencing the child and parent tables would be easy to diagnose. As it is you need to look up the constraint in the data dictionary.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes I am required to use trigger as this is an assignment. 
APC I got it, thank you! There was another foreign key in the employee table from the same department table that I didn't notice. 
I disabled that foreign key and then the code executed perfectly. Thanks for the help! ^_ ^